# Jasmine Maven Plugin including my scripts using file protocol

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-maven-plugin

I'm trying to add javascript unit testing to our project and found out about the [Jasmine Maven Plugin](http://searls.github.com/jasmine-maven-plugin/). I followed the directions and ended up with this in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <jsSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/js</jsSrcDir>
        <jsTestSrcDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/javascript</jsTestSrcDir>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I run `mvn jasmine:bdd` and get the expected output. I then go to `http://localhost:8234` and all I get is a blank screen. I look in the console and see this for each of my js files:

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///absolute/path/to/the/js/src/main/webapp/resources/js/myJS.js
```

The HTML for the page is including my scripts like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:/absolute/path/to/the/js/src/main/webapp/resources/js/myJS.js"></script>
```

So my question is, why is the plugin using the file protocol to inculde the js? Is this how it usually works? If so, how do I get my browser to allow the local resource? Is there any way to prevent it from doing this?

Just in case it matters, I tried this with both Firefox and Chrome, and I am using OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently and the problem was that my project was in a directory that had spaces in it.

This was on windows but it might be the same on OSX so it's worth a try.

So for instance my project was in a directory like this:

`C:\directory with spaces\myproject`

Changing it to the following fixed the `jasmine:bdd` command:

`C:\directorywithoutspaces\myproject`

Good luck!

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was! I took the spaces out and it works great now. Thanks!